# SimpleForm gem (Radio gives error, checkboxes work)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, simple-form-for

Why would SimpleForm give an error for a radio and not a checkbox?

### Check box works

```
 <%= f.association :color, :as => :check_boxes %>
```

### Radio gives error

```
 <%= f.association :color, :as => :radio %>
```

## error

```
No input found for radio
```

Comment: It's `:radio_buttons` not `:radio`